# Ruby self. vs @ in initialize

Tags: ruby

New in Ruby, trying to figure out why you would choose one variation over the other. Could you please write an example where one would be preferred over the other?

```
class User
    attr_accessor :username
    def initialize(username)
       self.username = username
    end
end

class User
    attr_accessor :username
    def initialize(username)
        @username = username
    end
end
```

Comment: Its an opinion-based question, second version seems more concise and also does not require `attr_accessor` to be defined - hence, my guess it is more preferable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same thing.

`self.username =` calls the `username=` function which is defined by attr_accessor. That function looks like this:

```
def username=(value)
  @username = value
end
```

As you can see, it is identical to the "alternative" you mentioned.

**EDIT** Using an accessor (i.e. calling the function defined by attr_accessor/reader/etc) is significantly faster than other forms of access. There are a few links in the comments which elaborate more on this.

Comment: And, `@username` can be used even if `attr_accessor` is not defined, `self.username` can be used only if `attr_accessor` is defined

Comment: It's worth noting that methods generated by `attr_accessor` tend to benchmark a lot faster than those composed manually. If possible, use the generators. If necessary, write your own.

Comment: So if you have an attr_accessor is it better to call it via @ or self.? or it doesn't make a difference at all?

Comment: @AlexAvlonitis using the accessor is usually faster. Here are a few discussions which explain/debate why: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494098/ruby-attr-accessor-vs-getter-setter-benchmark-why-is-accessor-faster), [2](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.0/files/method.h?#annotation=4081781&line=47)

Comment: Using attr_accessor may be faster then define an accessor method yourself, but is it really faster than directly setting the value, without defining an extra method? Our case seem not to be handled in these benchmarks.

Comment: *Actually*, you missed the trailing comma in line 2. Both pieces of code are 100% identical, because the trailing comma will lead Ruby to wait for a second argument to `attr_accessor`. That second argument is the return value of the `def`, which is a symbol denoting the name of the method being defined (`:initialize`). So, `def` will define the `initialize` method, but then `attr_accessor` will *immediately* overwrite that method with a getter for an instance variable named `@initialize`. So, both snippets will end up with the exact same four methods: `username`, `username=`, `initialize`, …

Comment: … and `initialize=` which do the exact same thing in both cases. The only difference is the content of the *first* `initialize` method, which however gets immediately overwritten with the exact same getter in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

One example is when you need read-only properties. Something like this:

```
class ProjectProcessor
  attr_reader :project # attr_reader, not attr_accessor

  def initialize(project)
    @project = project
  end

  # more code
end
```

Since `attr_reader` doesn't define a setter method, external code can't change `project` once processor is created (not in a convenient way, anyhow).

Comment: You could achieve the same with a `private` writer, though.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: true, but I find that it's very common that I set a property in the initializer and don't change it after. Creating a private writer for this seems... a bit too much hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Both cases are exactly equivalent because of the comma in line 2: the comma means that you are passing *two* arguments to `attr_accessor`, not one.

What is the second argument? Well, it's what comes after the comma, of course, which is the `def` expression. In older versions of Ruby, the return value of a method definition expression was implementation defined (in some implementations it returned `nil`, in some the compiled bytecode of the method), but in current versions of Ruby, the return value of a `def` expression is standardized to be a `Symbol` denoting the name of the method being `def`ined. So, in this case, the `def` expression evaluates to `:initialize`.

Now, because Ruby is a strict language, arguments are evaluated before they are passed, which means the `def initialize` is evaluated *first*, which defines an `initialize` method with one parameter.

However, immediately after that, `attr_accessor` is called with two arguments, `:username` and `:initialize`, and as a result, `attr_accessor` will create four methods: `username=`, `username`, `initialize=`, and `initialize`, thus overwriting the method we just defined with one that has no parameter.

That's why the two examples are the same: while the two `initialize` methods are different *initially*, they *immediately* get overwritten with an identical method.

(I guess, technically, you could observe the difference, if you managed to call `initialize` from a different thread at *just* the right time, directly after it is being defined the first time but before it is being overwritten. That's an extremely tiny window, though.)

Note that the code you posted will generate a warning to that effect:

```
user.rb:2: warning: method redefined; discarding old initialize
user.rb:3: warning: previous definition of initialize was here
```

You can see the effect of the strict evaluation of the arguments here in the line numbers: it complains that the method is being overwritten in line 2 but was previously defined on line 3, which actually comes after 2 but was evaluated *before* it.

This shows something I have written about over and over and over again: you should actually *read* the warnings. They were put in there for a reason.

Comment: The comma was a typo sorry. I copied just a part of it for the question and the comma slipped in