# In Ruby, is there a difference between `self.i` and `@i`?

Tags: ruby, oop, syntax, self

I thought, and tried, using @i and self.i interchangeably, but it gives an error:

```
class Animal
    def initialize i
        @i = i
    end
    def get_i
        self.i
    end
end
a = Animal.new("Sparky")
puts a.get_i()
```

Outputs:

```
source_file.rb:8:in `get_i':
undefined method `i' for #<Animal:0x000000010d5330 @i="Sparky"> 
    (NoMethodError)  
    from source_file.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

Is there any difference in terms of how the interpreter handles the code?

Comment: You should stick to either naming the variables and method either `@x`, `self.x` or `@i`, `self.i`. Mixing those two in your title and code just leads to unnecessary confusion.

Comment: You ask for `x` in your title and question but have `i` in your code

Comment: Yeah, I might have worded it poorly, sorry about that.

Answer (score 11):

There is, of course, a difference betwenn `self.i` and `@i`:

- `@i` will return the value assigned to the variable `@i`.
- Whereas `self.i` will return the value which was returned by a method named `i`.

Your `Animal` class has no `i` method defined, therefore the error message is correct.

When you want `self.i` to return the value of the `@i` variable then you need to create a `i` method like this

```
def i
  @i
end
```

or simply use the [`attr_reader`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) macro like this:

```
class Animal
  attr_reader :i

  #...
end
```

Comment: the `attr_reader` macro is for a  _list_ of getters! just use the simple getter you mentioned first.

Comment: @SapphireBrick I don't get you comment. The `attr_reader` can accept multiple arguments, but passing a single one is still valid.

Comment: valid, but almost no advantage. The reason it exists is to save _many_ lines of code when multiple getters are necessary.

Comment: `attr_reader` is not only saving a few lines of code and makes the code easier to read and to understand – what IMHO is already a great benefit. These macros are a [common Ruby idiom](https://rubystyle.guide/#attr_family) and the are implemented in `C` and therefore [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494098/ruby-attr-accessor-vs-getter-setter-benchmark-why-is-accessor-faster) than the pure Ruby getter or setter methods which they replace. Therefore I recommend already using the different `attr_` instead of trivial getter and setter methods.

Comment: no, on the contrary, it might confuse Ruby newbies; They'll wonder what it does. also, what does _faster_ matter if it's only executing it once, and you're only gaining like 10 ^ -6 of a second.  `atrr_reader` is a wonderful thing, but using it in that situation is like driving to your around-the-corner Supermarket.